# UILocalNotification won't fire

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

I'm writing an alarm clock iOS app. It's my first time using UILocalNotification. I'm getting the date from a date picker. I've formatted the dates to check whether my function was being passed the proper date, it was. I checked all of the needed properties for a UILocalNotification and I have them all and my notification still won't fire. Any ideas as to why? Thanks for the help.

```
#import "BIDAlarmViewController.h"

@interface BIDAlarmViewController () 

@end

@implementation BIDAlarmViewController

@synthesize datePicker; 

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{

[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)setReminderUsingDateFromDatePicker: (id)sender{

[self scheduleNotificationForDate: datePicker.date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm"];

NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];


NSLog(@"Button Pressed.. date: %@", formattedDateString);

UIAlertView  *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alarm activated"
                                                 message:@"Alarm has been set"
                                                delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
}

-(void) scheduleNotificationForDate: (NSDate*)date {

UILocalNotification *alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (alarm) {
    alarm.fireDate = date;
    alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
    alarm.soundName = @"alarmsound.caf";
    alarm.alertBody = @"Test message...";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
}
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you implemented the didReceiveLocalNotification method in your app delegate?

Comment: No, I haven't. I think I brushed over that. Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you expect to receive notification, if you had no method to receive it??

Comment: Probably just assumed it would show up in notification center - that's what I thought the first time I did that :)

Comment: @HotLicks I'm new to app development. Can you explain why that method needed to be in the app delegate to receive the notification?

Comment: Because otherwise there's nowhere for you to get control when a notification fires.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveLocalNotification:

Make sure you've implemented the referenced method in your app delegate like so:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  NSLog(@"Notification fired"!);
}
```

Notes from Apple on implementing this method:

> Local notifications are similar to remote push notifications, but
>   differ in that they are scheduled, displayed, and received entirely on
>   the same device. An application can create and schedule a local
>   notification, and the operating system then delivers it at the
>   schedule date and time. If it delivers it when the application is not
>   active in the foreground, it displays an alert, badges the application
>   icon, or plays a sound—whatever is specified in the
>   UILocalNotification object. If the application is running in the
>   foreground, there is no alert, badging, or sound; instead, the
>   application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method is called if the
>   delegate implements it.
>
> The delegate can implement this method if it wants to be notified that
>   a local notification occurred. For example, if the application is a
>   calendar application, it can enumerate its list of calendar events to
>   determine which ones have due dates that have transpired or are about
>   to transpire soon. It can also reset the application icon badge
>   number, and it can access any custom data in the local-notification
>   object’s userInfo dictionary.

Comment: What goes inside the body of the function in the app delegate?

Comment: What do you want to do? Generally I just pop up a UIAlertView with the message from the notification. It's really just up to you though!

Comment: Nice. That's what I thought. Thanks again for the help!